Using INDIRECT in Google Sheets to reference to reference a table's named column
My use case is more complex than this but I think this example illustrates my problem clearly.
I have a simple table in Google Sheets. It is called test.




Name
1st Number
2nd Number




Hat
1
2


Cat
4
8


Mat
16
32



I am able to return the sum of the values in its 2nd column by using the formula: =sum(test[1st Number])
However, I am unable to copy that exact string of test[1st Number] into a cell to reference it using INDIRECT =sum(indirect(B1)) to get the sum of that column.
The error I am getting is:
Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'test[1st Number]'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.


I am hoping that there is an error in my formula rather than it being impossible to reference a named column in a table using INDIRECT.
Solution
I used index and match as recommended by @doubleunary below  to have the formula
=sum(index(test, 0, match(C1, test[#HEADERS], 0)))

referencing the string 1st Number in cell C1


Avoid adding solutions in questions. Either edit the existing answer or just add an new answer.

Structured table references are not currently (December 2024) supported by the indirect() function. Use this pattern instead:
=sum(index(Table1, 0, match(B1, Table1[#HEADERS], 0)))

...where cell B1 matches the name of the column you want to sum.
See Use table references in Google Sheets.

To support the answer, INDIRECT states You can't use table references in =INDIRECT yet. Try IMPORTRANGE instead.

@Saddles thanks. I don't think structured table references work reliably in importrange() either, and have previously mentioned that to Google. It's not a good workaround in any case, because it will cause trouble when you make a copy of the spreadsheet.

Thanks @doubleunary, I used the formula =sum(index(test, 0, match(C1, test[#HEADERS], 0))) with C1 containing 1st Number and the reference works.

@doubleunary, I've submitted feedback in the article as well, since the more people that report an issue, the more that it's prioritized by Google.
